# Macruby: plug an attr_accessor to a controller

Tags: ruby, cocoa, macruby

I am starting macruby and I am following this tutorial: http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/03/12/creating-our-very-first-mac-application-with-ruby-how-exciting/

I am stuck at the "Hooking our MyWindowController up to our window" section where I have to “plug our window’s label into our MyWindowController‘s my_label outlet”.

My problem is that when I ctrl+click on my new NSObject to my label I have no popup appearing or something like that.

Does anyone has an idea why I can link my controller to my window?
I am using xcode 4.5.2 and macruby 0.12

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the issue. I upgrade XCode to 4.5.2 and reinstalled macruby